# postgres nested loop and compare strings

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have to compare strings in 2 tables.

I'm doing it by the next query

```
@set wordB = '%laptop%'

select n1.item_name,n2.item_name , similarity(n1.item_name,n2.item_name) 
from (
  select * 
  from "tableA" ta 
  where ta.item_name ilike :wordB
) n1
  join (
    select * 
    from "tableb" tb 
    where tb.item_name ilike :wordB
  ) n2 on n2.item_name <> n1.item_name 
      and n1.item_name % n2.item_name
```

the logic works fine but it's very slow (ofc), how can I improve it?

and more, I did this 2 months ago and I forgot the meaning of

```
and n1.item_name % n2.item_name
```

I try searching on google and don't remember what this is do. (it makes the result better for me but I don't remember why i put it

Comment: `%` is the "similar enough" operator from pg_trgm.

Comment: Please show the the output of `EXPLAIN (ANALYZE, BUFFERS) <that query>`, or if that never finishes than just of `EXPLAIN <that query>`

Comment: You can compare to multiple words `where tb.item_name ilike any(array[....])`

Comment: i think a full text search or elastcsearch for big databases, would help as you can get the simlilarity without without text functions, this should be faster

Comment: This will always be slow, no matter what. You can make it somewhat less slow with a trigram index.